# Amazon Redshift modify view definition created by other user

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm trying to alter the definition of a view, which was created by another user, but I'm getting the following error:

ERROR: 42501: must be owner of relation *my_view*

Are there any privileges that my user can be granted in order to be able to modify the view?

Thanks!

Mihai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to override it you'd need to either be a superuser or log in as a superuser temporarily (I'd recommend the later).

In the following example it's `CREATEUSER` that makes this new user a superuser.

```
CREATE USER my_superuser WITH PASSWORD 'SuperComplexPassword1234' CREATEUSER IN GROUP superusers_group;
```